# Rails Different types of Model have different number of and type of fields

Tags: ruby-on-rails, model-view-controller, database-design

In rails web app, user can "make" a `Document`. There are different types of documents :

1. `Loan`
2. `Business`
3. `Insurance`

Each type of Document will have *some* things in common such as: `account_num`, `doc_id`, at least `1` `name`, but then they have different attributes.

For example:

`Loan` is only doc with a `loan_type` field

`Business` documents can have `1+` `name` attributes

If these docs may have different number of attributes, do they need to be completely separate `model`s, or is there a way to incorporate a `doc_type` attribute for `Document` which then reveals what, and how many, attributes are associated with the `Document`? If so, what would that look like?

Answer (score 2):

What you're describing is the express purpose of [single-table inheritance](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Base.html#class-ActiveRecord::Base-label-Single+table+inheritance) in Rails.

Use one table with a super-set of all the fields from all the models. Add a `type` column, and then create your three models, inheriting from a base model, and you're pretty much done.

Comment: ah so the number of fields in the table would be the max-number required by any one of the types, is that right? Then for types not requiring all the fields, those will simply be blank or `null`?

Comment: am i off-base with my guess in the comment?

Comment: I get how STI would help me, but I really do not like how non-normalized it is...

Answer (score 1):

Depends on what you're going to need, but in general if your models have a strong commonality that part can all be in the same table, and include a type column that specifies the class name. This is called single table inheritance.

Any differences between the models give you some interesting options. If there are only a few differences, the columns could simply be included. If there are several, or the columns in question may be only sparsely populated, you can introduce a new table for the extra columns that belongs_to one of the models. For example, you could have an alternate_names table for businesses.

```
class AlternateNames < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :business
end
```

In the unlikely case that you don't need to search on the extra data, you can even keep it in the same table, with a column named something like extra_data, and serialize a hash of extra attributes. Each class can handle this data as appropriate.

```
class Document < ActiveRecord::Base
  # your code
  serializes :extra_data
end

class Business < Document
  def names
    [name] + extra_data[:names]
  end
end
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, esp. the bit about `extra_data`. As for STI, I really don't like how non-normalized it is. Do you know of how to do this without using STI? I.e. using a `DocumentType` table or something... I'm kind of at a loss

Comment: Implementing proper STI, it should wind up being more normalized--the stuff that is in common is all in the same table/class (Document), and then a table such as BusinessData would have a document_id, belong_to a Business, and have any extra columns you need on it. The Business class would have methods to access the special data, but rely on Document for accessing the common data.

Comment: Implementing proper STI, it should wind up being more normalized--the stuff that is in common is all in the same table/class (Document), and then a table such as BusinessData would have a document_id, belong_to a Business, and have any extra columns you need on it. The Business class would have methods to access the special data, but rely on Document for accessing the common data.

Comment: Everything after `--the stuff that is in common...` -- are you describing what it would look like with STI, or doing it differently? I think you are describing the non-STI route there, just want to make sure I get you

Comment: That is describing STI, actually. Any time you have different logic pointing at the same table, it can be regarded as single-table inheritance. Even the extra_data option I described above is a less-rigorous take on STI. If you don't want to use STI for whatever reason, you'll be stuck with the duplication of those common columns on different tables. (Honestly, unless there are a lot of them, it's not really that bad if you do that. You can always define and include a module for handling the parts that are common between the classes.)